# How to keep other div from stopping mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu, where if I place mouse over, it'll expand, and when mouse goes out of the menu, it retracts (ie. it works). Problem is, that when the menu expands over another div, and I move the cursor over that other div (while the menu is open, and overlapping the other div), the menu disappears. How could I disable the divs menu destroying feature?

CSS:

> ```
>   nav ul ul {
>   display: none;
>
>    z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul li:hover > ul {
>   display: block;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul {
> background: #efefef; 
> background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
> background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
> background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
> box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
> padding: 0 20px;
> border-radius: 10px;  
> list-style: none;
> position: relative;
> display: inline-table;
> z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul:after {
>   content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul li {
>   float: left;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul li:hover {
>   background: #4b545f;
>   background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
>   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
>   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>   nav ul li:hover a {
>       color: #fff;
>       z-index: 888;
>   }
>
>
> nav ul li a {
>   display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
>   color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul ul {
>   background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
>   position: absolute; top: 100%;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul ul li {
>   float: none; 
>   border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
>   border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
>   position: relative;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
>
> nav ul ul li a {
>   padding: 15px 40px;
>   color: #fff;
>   z-index: 888;
> } 
>
>
> nav ul ul li a:hover {
>   background: #4b545f;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
>
> nav ul ul ul {
>   position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
>   z-index: 888;
> }
> ```

Relative HTML:

> ```
> Headers and stuff here before this:
>
> <div id="Tuotekategoriat" style="position: absolute; width: 862px; height: 60px; z-index: 2; left: 172px; top: 25px"> <nav>   <ul>
>   <li><a>Ratsastajalle</a>            <ul>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Housut">Housut</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Takit">Takit</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Hanskat">Hanskat</a></li>
>               <li><a href="Kypärät">Kypärät</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Raipat">Raipat</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Saappaat">Saappaat</a></li>          </ul>       </li>       <li><a>Hevoselle</a>            <ul>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Satulat">Satulat</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Satulatarvikkeet">Satulatarvikkeet</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Suitset">Suitset</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Loimet">Loimet</a></li>
>               <li><a href="products.php?category=Rintaremmit">Rintaremmit</a></li>            </ul>
>   </li>       <li><a>Hoitotuotteet</a>            <ul>            </ul>       </li>
>   <li><a>Rehut ja lisäravinteet</a>           </li>
>               <li><a>Yritys</a>               <ul>
>               <li><a href="#">Yhteystiedot</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Ehdot</a></li>          </ul>       </li>
>
>   </ul> </nav>
>
> </div>
>
> and another div here:
>
> <div id="layer21"  style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 100px; z-index: 4; left: 185px; top: 160px"> test </div>
> ```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle showing the interesting behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/8BN4Y/

Answer (score 1):

The navigation's parent has a `z-index` of 2.

`<div id="Tuotekategoriat" style="position: absolute; width: 862px; height: 60px; z-index: 2; left: 172px; top: 25px">`

The content under the navigation has a `z-index` of 4.

`<div id="layer21"  style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 100px; z-index: 4; left: 185px; top: 160px"> test </div>`

That being said, the content under the navigation will always appear over top of the navigation. You can either remove the `z-index` values, or make the navigation have a higher `z-index` value..

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nq7ZY/) - set the navigation to a `z-index` of 5.

Answer (score 0):

removing `position: absolute` attribute from the div below the menu stops it being destroyed.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rULx/